# Implicit Wait Timeout not working

Tags: vb.net, selenium

Was trying to block execution for 10 seconds properly with `VB.Net` `Selenium`, so found out about Implicit Wait on SO, and found this example.

```
        driver.Manage.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        Debug.WriteLine(driver.PageSource)
```

The problem is, I set a break point on both lines and `Debug.WriteLine` is called nearly instantly.  I've read on here I shouldn't use `Thread.Sleep` here, so why is the timeout not having the desired effect?

Thanks!

Comment: I had read the documentation, I was just confused because ExplicitWait polls for expected condition on a specific element, which I wasn't really trying to do (notice my example code, it has nothing to do with polling a specific element, but simply waiting 10 seconds before continuing execution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An `implicit` wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

May be you missed the parentheses:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

You can also try using below:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Alternatively you can use `ExplicitWait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(--ELEMENT TO BE VISIBLE--));
```

> It is more extendible in the means that you can set it up to wait for any condition you might like. Usually, you can use some of the prebuilt `ExpectedConditions` to wait for elements to become `clickable`, `visible`, `invisible` etc.

Solution is in `C#.NET`. You might need to convert some syntax in `VB.NET`.

Comment: Designer shows ImplicitlyWait is Obsolete and to use ImplicitWait.  Also you gave me C# code, no big deal though, I can mentally omit the semicolons...

I added the parenthesis as you suggested, and no change.  It moves to line 2 of my example instantly, rather than taking 10 seconds like I am trying to achieve without Thread.Sleep

Comment: I updated the answer. You might need to convert some syntax in `VB.NET`. I resolved this in `C#.NET`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try ExplicitWait then.  If it works I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Ok bro! Thank you too.